# synchronized on Map key

Tags: java, multithreading, kotlin, telegram, synchronized

I use the following method in the code of my Telegram bot:

```
fun save(tUser: org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.objects.User): User {
        val userId = tUser.id;
        synchronized(this) {
            val user = userRepository.findById(userId).orElse(User(userId))
            user.apply {
                username = tUser.userName
                firstName = tUser.firstName
                lastName = tUser.lastName
                languageCode = tUser.languageCode
                lastMessageReceived = Instant.now()
            }
            return userRepository.save(user)
        }
    }
```

the use of block **synchronized** is caused by the following reason - Telegram server sends messages in multiple threads, so two requests **from the same user** can arrive at the same time.

Thus, the search and insertion in the database of users is performed strictly in one thread.
But there is no need to synchronize on **whole controller object(this)** (processing of different users can go in parallel), i.e. i need to synchronize on, say, ConcurrenthashMap key, for example like this:

```
    private val users: ConcurrentHashMap<Long, Long> = ConcurrentHashMap()

    fun save(tUser: org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.objects.User): User {
        val userId = users.putIfAbsent(tUser.id, tUser.id)!!
        synchronized(userId) {
            val user = userRepository.findById(userId).orElse(User(userId))
            user.apply {
                username = tUser.userName
                firstName = tUser.firstName
                lastName = tUser.lastName
                languageCode = tUser.languageCode
                lastMessageReceived = Instant.now()
            }
            return userRepository.save(user)
        }
    }
```

**would it be correct?**

Here I see another problem - the threads are slowing down on **ConcurrentHashMap**, although not as much as in the first case, where the DB is accessed inside block **synchronized(this)**

Comment: I believe synchronizing on `Long` isn't really a good idea. You can use the same technique, but store `ReentrantLock` objects in the map (or just `Any()`) and synchronize on them. Downside is that the map will grow with time and it is not trivial to remove unused locks.

Comment: What is the actual implementation of `userRepository`? Any reasonable relational Db will have no issue with concurrent selects and provide fine control over what happens on inserts and updates

Comment: @DavidSoroko,
i use postgres.
If I don't use the lock:

A situation may arise when the same user (absent in the database) comes in two threads.
And then the first query will be executed successfully, but the second will crash with the violation of the primary key

Comment: Synchronizing server side will not solve the issue if you run multiple instances. You could consider ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING as an alternative:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/sql-insert.html

Comment: or just ignore/swallow the unique constraint violation exception on insert in your code. Amounts to pretty much the same thing.